# confused between change-of-basis matrix and matrix of linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

This is the problem I am trying to solve.

> Let $\beta_1 = \bigl\{ (1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,1) \bigr\}$ and
> $\beta_2 = \bigl\{ (2,1,1), (1,2,1), (−1,1,1) \bigr\}$
> be two ordered bases of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Then find a matrix representing the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ which transforms $\beta_1$ to $\beta_2$.

**The above problem has been posted multiple times on Stackexchange and everytime different solutions have been given.**  I am totally lost on what is the correct approach. I believe to some extent I am confusing change-of-basis matrix with matrix of linear transformation. Which of the below solution is correct?

1. **Solution 1:** [Find linear transformation using change of basis matrix.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202054/find-linear-transformation-using-change-of-basis-matrix) (I personally feel this is correct)
2. **Solution 2:** [Linear transformation matrix wrto 2 basis $\beta = \{ (1,1,0), (1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$ and $\beta' = \{ (2,1,1), (1,2,1),(-1,1,1)\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2622253/linear-transformation-matrix-wrto-2-basis-beta-1-1-0-1-0-1-0-1-1?rq=1)

Can someone please advise me on what is the correct approach to handle problems of above nature?

Comment: Make this question self-contained: Instead of links, state clearly what the two methods are which you refer to.

Comment: let me make that change. should  I put the links as references?

Comment: If your explanation is clear, no need for the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a linear map $T$ such that $T \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$, $T \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}$, and $T \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$.  To find a matrix for $T$ with respect to the standard basis using the change of basis formula, you'd note that $[T]^{\beta_1}_{\beta_2}$ is the identity matrix (the notation means "the matrix of $T$ with respect to initial basis $\beta_1$ and final basis $\beta_2$") and the change of basis formula says
$$ [T]^\mathcal{E}_\mathcal{E} = [\operatorname{id}]^{\beta_2}_\mathcal{E} [T] ^{\beta_1}_{\beta_2} [\operatorname{id}]^\mathcal{E}_{\beta_1}$$
where $\mathcal{E}$ is the standard basis.  The matrix in the middle is the identity, so the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis is $[\operatorname{id}]^{\beta_2}_\mathcal{E} [\operatorname{id}]^\mathcal{E}_{\beta_1}$.  The first of these matrices is easy: it records how to express the basis elements from $\beta_2$ as linear combinations of the standard basis, so it is just the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}2&1&-1\\1&2&1\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$ whose columns are the vectors from $\beta_2$.  To find $[\operatorname{id}]^\mathcal{E}_{\beta_1}$ you could note that it is the inverse of $[\operatorname{id}]^{\beta_1}_\mathcal{E}$, which you can calculate like before then invert, or you could compute it directly using the definition of the matrix of a linear map.  Either way you'd get $\begin{pmatrix}1/2&1/2&-1/2\\1/2&-1/2&1/2\\-1/2&1/2&1/2\end{pmatrix}$, and the product is $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&0&-1\\1&0&1\\1/2&1/2&1/2\end{pmatrix}$.  You can check that this matrix really does map the vectors in $\beta_1$ to those in $\beta_2$, e.g. $A \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\1/2\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1/2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

It's not necessary to use the change of basis machinery unless you want to practise doing it.  You can just proceed directly by solving the system of linear equations for the entries of $[T]^\mathcal{E}_\mathcal{E}$ given by the requirements that it maps the entries of $\beta_1$ to $\beta_2$. Alternatively, and this is the method showin in the first link, if you can find scalars $a_{ij}$ such that $\mathbf{e}_j = \sum_i a_{ij}\beta_{1i}$ (where $\mathbf{e}_j$ is the $j$th standard basis vector and $\beta_{1i}$ means the $i$th basis vector from $\beta_1$) then applying $T$ to both sides and using linearity you have $T(\mathbf{e}_j) = \sum_i a_{ij}\beta_{2i}$, and this column vector is the $j$th column of $[T]^\mathcal{E}_\mathcal{E}$.  Of course, these scalars $a_{ij}$ are exactly the entries of $[\operatorname{id}]^\mathcal{E}_{\beta_1}$ and $\sum_i a_{ij}\beta_{2i}$ is the $j$th column of the matrix product $[\operatorname{id}]^{\beta_2}_\mathcal{E}[\operatorname{id}]^\mathcal{E}_{\beta_1}$, so this is equivalent to the method above.

In your second link, the answers don't look correct to me.  One of them computes the two matrices $M=[\operatorname{id}]^{\beta_1}_\mathcal{E}$ and $N= [\operatorname{id}]^{\beta_2}_\mathcal{E}$ in my notation (unfortunately the other way round to theirs) then says that $[T]^{\beta_2}_{\beta_1} =N^{-1}M$, but  $[T]^{\beta_2}_{\beta_1}$ is the identity and in any case $N^{-1}M$ is not the matrix that we want.

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes sense, however could you please help me understand why  $\left[T\right]_{\beta_{1}}^{\beta_{2}}$ is identity?
Also, when should one use change of basis matrix as in this case using that leads to incorrect answer.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo on my part.  It's $[T]^{\beta_1}_{\beta_2}$ which is the identity matrix (because $T(\beta_{1j}) = \beta_{2j}$).  You can always use the change of basis formula as long as you use it correctly - the answer in your second link just makes a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In order to represent a linear transformation $T: V \to W$ by a matrix, we have to have a basis in mind for both vector spaces. Then, then each column of the matrix gives the weights of the *image* of the basis vector from the source when expressed as a linear combination of the basis vectors in the target.

In other words, given basis $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ for $V$ and $\{w_1, \dots, w_m\}$ for $W$, the matrix $A = \bigl[ a_{ij} \bigr]$ representing the transformation *in these bases* is defined by
$$
T(v_j) = \sum_i a_{ij} w_i. 
$$

---

You are looking for the transformation that converts basis $\beta_1$ to $\beta_2$ **in the standard basis** for $\mathbb{R}^3$ in both source and target. A conceptually straightforward way to write this down (following your first linked question) is to transform $\beta_1$ to the standard basis $\varepsilon$, then transform $\varepsilon$ to $\beta_2$.

How? Well, if you form a matrix with the basis vectors of $\beta_1$ as columns, then that change-of-basis matrix represents the transformation
from vectors in $\beta_1$ to the standard basis, i.e. the first vector is expressed as the linear combination
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} 
= 1 \begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} 
+ 1 \begin{bmatrix} 
0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} 
+ 0 \begin{bmatrix} 
0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
etc.

Thus, the matrix you seek is matrix followed by the *inverse* change-of-basis matrix for basis $\beta_2$ since were converting *from* the standard matrix. In other words, you seek the matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer, can you tell me why the solution posted below is different https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202054/find-linear-transformation-using-change-of-basis-matrix 
this is the cause of my confusion

Comment: multiplying A with any of the β1's element should give corresponding element of β2, correct?
But that does not seem to happen, if I calculate A it comes out as below 
$A =\begin{pmatrix}-1/3 & 4/3 & 1/3\\1 & -1 & 0\\-2/3 &2/3&2/3\end{pmatrix}$

but multiplying A by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 &1\end{pmatrix}$ gives $\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 &0\end{pmatrix}$ which is not in β2.
So isn't that incorrect as A is supposed to map first basis to second?